# Would somebody like to try to make a version of this unresolved question from English Language & Usage suitable for our site?

Tags: discussion, migration

[What is the name of the phoneme produced in an upper-class Briton's pronunciation of the word “Duke”? What's different in the articulation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27362/what-is-the-name-of-the-phoneme-produced-in-an-upper-class-britons-pronunciation)

The question or at least one of the comments included a sound sample of an RP speaker who pronounces "duke" in a way that sounds like "juke" to my ear.

People were talking about palatalization and palatal glides but we all ran out of expertise to fully resolve it.

I'm certain there's a good question in it but I lack enough knowledge to move it here in a good way most suitable for out site. Would one of you like to give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the question in itself would be a fine question, as would many possible follow-up questions (what are historical patterns of palatalization/depalatalization; is there a relationship between class and palatalization including in history; how does the palatalization of /u/ in RP compare to palatalization in Russian or Old French).

Furthermore, it would be a good forum to bring more linguistic expertise into the answer.

I may just be being snooty, but there are fundamental errors in the answer to that question as well as the follow-up comments including transcription (which brackets to use) and also philosophical errors including mixing up palatalization and the palatal stop.

Comment: OK I shall import just the question as is and see what becomes of it here.